# Is this question ready for reopen?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

Looks good to me now, I made some edits and sussed out what I'm fairly certain the author really wanted to ask, if it looks good please reopen otherwise any tips? I think it should be good now.

[What is the current status of software support for JPEG-2000?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195359/from-tiff-to-jpeg-2000-can-i-use-jpeg-2000-now-at-2013)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

Even though it "only" had a couple of reopen votes, With the edits I think it deserves another chance.